# PyMilvus Error while making ChatGPT-VoiceAssistant

Tags: python, grpc, chatgpt-api, grpc-python, elevenlabs

Error :-

```
\[WARNING\] PyMilvus:

\[has_collection\] retry:4, cost: 0.27s, reason: \<\_MultiThreadedRendezvous: StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNAVAILABLE: ipv4:example:19530: Connection refused\>
```

im not sure if this is due to the default port becoming unreachable or something else.please anyone help me to resolve this problem.

### Installation

1. Clone the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/JoshuaAFerguson/ChatGPT-VoiceAssistant.git
```

2. Change directory to the cloned repository:

```
cd ChatGPT-VoiceAssistant
```

3. Install the required dependencies:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

4. Rename example.env to .env and add your API keys

### Expectations:-

ChatGPT-VoiceAssistant is a Python-based voice assistant that leverages the capabilities of ChatGPT, Whisper, ElevenLabs, and PicoVoice. This voice assistant allows users to interact with their devices using voice commands and provides intelligent responses based on the user's input.

To start the voice assistant, run the following command:

```
python assistant.py
```

After starting the voice assistant, it will wait for the wake word [porcupine] before it starts recording. After saying the wake word it will record the next 5 seconds of speach. You can interact with it using voice commands. Speak your queries clearly, and the assistant will provide intelligent responses based on your input.

Answer (score 0):

The error output shows that you are trying to connect to the address `ipv4:example:19530`. That string is somewhere in your code, and the string `example` should be replaced with the actual IP address that you need to connect to.